# Why would a region of memory be marked non-cached?

Tags: memory, caching, embedded

In an embedded application, we have a table describing the various address ranges that are valid on our target board. This table is used to set up the MMU.
The RAM address range is marked as cacheable, but other regions are not. Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a memory region is accessed by both hardware and software simultaneously (EX: hardware configuration register or scatter-gather list for DMA), this region **must** be defined as non-cached. For actual DMA, the memory buffer can be defined as cached, and in most cases, it is advisable for the buffer to be cached to allow the application level speedy access to that buffer. It's the driver's responsibility to flush/invalidate cache before passing the buffer to DMA or the application.

Small update, above **must** is not correct in case we have a specialized hardware, i.e. Cache Coherency Interconnect (CCI) which will synchronize access of various hardware blocks to memory.

Comment: Are there any other best-practice examples of non-cacheble data (except DMA case)?

Answer (score 20):

This is done so that the processor does not use stale values due to caching.
When you access (regular) cached RAM, the processor can "remember" the value that you accessed.  The next time you look at that same memory location, the processor will return the value it remembers without looking in RAM.  This is caching.

If the content of the location can change without the processor knowing as could be the case if you have a memory-mapped device (an FPGA returning some data packets for example), the processor could return the value "remembered" from last time, which would be wrong.

To avoid this problem, you mark that address space as non-cacheable.  This ensures the processor does not try to remember the value.

Comment: I'm working on one such embedded project, where a part of my DRAM is marked as Non-cacheable shadow memory. This is in fact a part of my physical memory and not a memory mapped device. Such memory regions used for scratchpad and error checking wont be cached.

Comment: Are there any other best-practice examples of non-cacheble data (except HW case)? –

Answer (score 7):

Any memory region used for DMA or other hardware interactions should not be cached.

Answer (score 2):

In consideration of cache coherence. Assume there is a location X in memory that can be accessed by devices using DMA, so cpu would not be awared when the devices write a new value into X. If cpu have cached the content of X before, when cpu need the value it will get it from cache. In this case, cpu gets stale value. Similarly, devices using DMA might read a stale value either.

From wiki [Direct_memory_access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's used for memory-mapped I/O?

Answer (score 1):

Modern controllers can use L2 cache for DMA, meaning they preserve the coherency of the cached memory region used for DMA accesses.  This is also termed as "snoop-able memory transactions" performed by the controller (via DMA).

Answer (score -1):

Some areas like Flash can be read in one cycle, so do not need to be cached.

Comment: I need some of this 1 nsec flash.

Comment: I'm not aware of any flash that can be accessed in a single clock cycle. Actually, I'm not aware of any operation at all that occurs in a single clock cycle. Even NOPs take around 4 cycles on most architectures from what I know.