# Is it possible to bypass L1 cache in a multicore processor

Tags: c, caching, x86-64, multicore

In Modern multicore processors, we normally have a local L1 cache but a shared L2 cache. Is it possible to bypass the L1 cache for some portion of the memory while still using L2 cache for it? I want to do this to improve timing predictability, at the cost of performance it may be.

Comment: Do you use a real-time OS ?

Comment: Bypass L1 on reads or on writes or both?

Comment: You can either get "strongly uncacheable" or "cacheable". Choose either. Keep in mind that the timing predictability won't change much, since x86 is cache coherent. Also, unless this is supposed to be a strongly real time system (which you cannot really do on x86, thanks to things like SMM and friends), you should **not** care about such things; the CPU is generally smarter about its internals than you.

Comment: @osgx: On both reads and writes.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, see my [survey paper on cache bypassing](https://www.academia.edu/24842555/A_Survey_of_Cache_Bypassing_Techniques) for more details and examples

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to bypass the L1 cache on mainstream CPUs.

However, to achieve your goal (i.e. avoid cache misses that may cause variation in timings mesurements), you may try to ask your compiler to prefetch the data into the cache.

If you use GCC or LLVM, see [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins).

However, your question is quite vague, and I am unsure that your proposal will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Caches**

I strongly suspect that you have misunderstood what a cache does and what it is for.

Caches are transparent from the point of view of memory contents. If one core writes to a memory location then every other core whose caches (L1, L2, L3 etc), shared or not, happen to be caching that location will get updated also.

Note that that does *not* mean that the cores aren't able to race for the value. You can still have a race condition whereby one core reading a location fractionally before another writes it 'gets the wrong value'. Furthermore that will happen whether or not your CPU has caches of any sort. To solve that 'ordering' problem you have to use semaphores or other IPC primitives in your source code.

Some cache systems do allow you to 'drop hints' to them. Matthieu Rouget gave an example of that with __builtin_prefetch. These sorts of things allow the programmer to tell the cache system that it might well be worth getting some data in advance. Some systems (e.g. PowerPC 7450) sort of allowed the programmer to use part of the cache as memory instead of cache, kind of the ultimate in programmer cache control.

However, none of these things make any difference to the view of memory that all the caches have. If one cache's contents get updated, the rest are also updated.

**Caches and Performance Programming**

The very best programmers are able to extract peak performance from a CPU by coding around the behaviour of the cache. In that realm one generally finds oneself wishing that the cache wasn't there at all. The ultimate embodiment of this is the Cell processor in the PS3. The maths cores on that have no cache at all. Instead you have to in effect do all your own data fetching and write back yourself in your source code, rather than leave it up to some cache to second guess what data your program is going to ask for. Get it right and the performance is still blisteringly good.

**Bus Snooping**

Some CPUs don't have cache bus snooping, which can be a particular problem when writing device drivers. Bus snooping is a mechanism whereby the CPU caches spot the content of memory being updated by something other than the CPU cores (e.g. by a DMA controller reading data from a device). And the same the other way round - DMAs from memory get values currently stuck in cache. AFAIK almost all CPUs these days do bus snooping, so that is not likely to be a problem.

On systems with IO as well as memory address spaces (e.g. Intel) I don't think that I/O address space is cached anyway. For systems with memory mapped devices their memory is generally not cached either, and the OS sets up the CPU that way (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90204/why-would-a-region-of-memory-be-marked-non-cached)).

**Timing Predictability**

To return to the reason for your question - timing predictability. You may be using the wrong technology. If your system has timing constraints whereby the problem is variations in main memory write times, then frankly using a multicore CPU sounds like the wrong thing in the first place. **@Griwes** is quite right on that point (and indeed the entire comment). You'll more likely need to resort to a pure hardware design, something along the lines of an FPGA (no comments about whether firmware is really software please!).

If, as I suspect, you're actually trying to avoid using semaphores and other IPC primitives to synchronise two threads in your system then you're not going to succeed, shared caches or not. You need to use semaphores and such to make your code work properly.