# Best practice of using non-cacheable memory

Tags: c, linux, caching, memory-management, linux-kernel

I read the post [Why would a region of memory be marked non-cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90204/why-would-a-region-of-memory-be-marked-non-cached)
but there are no reasons mentioned other than memory regions for "with-hardware communications" (e.g. DMA).

Are there any other good reasons to mark memory as non-cacheable?

P.S. seems that marking memory as non-cacheable from user-space can be done through [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_NOCACHE` flag, isn't it?

**UPD**

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache):

> Marking some memory ranges as non-cacheable can improve performance,
> by avoiding caching of memory regions that are rarely re-accessed.
> This avoids the overhead of loading something into the cache without
> having any reuse. Cache entries may also be disabled or locked
> depending on the context.

Roughly speaking, it's about not clogging the cache with data that is unnecessary for caching. I.e., not littering.
Seems that wikipedia is somewhat misinforming us, because the one cannot improve performance such a way on any widly-used OS..

Comment: I don't think so. And MAP_NOCACHE is on Mac (I don't know why)

Comment: Memory would be marked as non-cacheable so that the CPU always reads the current contents and writes immediately store the value. What else might access the memory? A DMA controller? A Bus Master (aka 2nd-party DMA)? A co-processor? A slave processor? It's anything external to the CPU that has access to main memory.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any other good reasons to mark memory as non-cacheable?

Not really, not on Linux at least. There are however a lot of possible drawbacks. In fact, you cannot create uncached mappings in Linux with `mmap`.

The `MAP_NOCACHE` flag you mention does not exist for Linux, it exists for macOS, and even there it does not seem to mean uncached memory, but is related to the kernel page cache instead (see [`man 2 mmap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/mmap.2.html) for macOS).

One application that could be considered interesting for uncached memory mappings is securing data from architectural cache side-channels, such as [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)). The possibility to provide userspace with the ability to create uncached mappings was in fact considered not so long ago for the implementation of the `memfd_secret` syscall, but was [scrapped under the suggestion of Andy Lutomirski](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/CALCETrXr-9ABs7rzXcCrh1VXn-15AfpwjA6bQA7aU9Ta7DR+bw@mail.gmail.com/#t), who explained:

> I'm still not ready to ACK uncached mappings on x86.  I'm fine with
> the concept of allowing privileged users to create UC memory on x86
> for testing and experimentation, but it's a big can of worms in
> general.  The issues that immediately come to mind are:
>
> - Performance and DoS potential.  UC will have bizarre, architecture- and platform-dependent performance characteristics.  For all I know,
>   even the access semantics might be architecture dependent.  I'm not
>   convinced it's possible to write portable code in C using the uncached
>   feature.  I'm also concerned that certain operation (unaligned locks,
>   for example, and possibly any locked access) will trigger bus locks on
>   x86, which, depending on CPU and kernel config will either DoS all
>   other CPUs or send signals.  (Or cause the hypervisor to terminate or
>   otherwise penalize the the VM, which would be nasty.)
> - Correctness.  I have reports that different x86 hypervisors do different things with UC mappings, including treating them as regular
>   WB mappings.  So the memory type you get out when you ask for
>   "uncached" might not actually be uncached.
>
> UC is really an MMIO feature, not a "protect my data" feature. Abusing
> it to protect data is certainly interesting, but I'm far from
> convinced that it's wise.  I'm especially unconvinced that
> monkey-patching a program to use uncached memory when it expects
> regular malloced memory is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Thanks! A bit updated question, added a description of the application context

Comment: @NK-cell saw the update. Yeah, I would say that the use case mentioned by Wikipedia is pretty wild. Uncommon/unlikely for a general purpose OS. While it may happen that for some specific use case you need UC memory, there are definitely more cons than pros to using it in general.